# Finding an equation for the line on a plane that makes a specific angle

Tags: calculus

Find equations for the line in the plane z = 3 that makes an angle of $\pi/6$rad with $\hat{i}$ and an angle of $\pi/3$rad with $\hat{j}$. Describe the reasoning behind your answer.

The solution says that since the line makes an angle of $\pi/6$ with $\hat{i}$ and $\pi/3$ with $\hat{j}$, we can use this angle to get a vector parallel to that line as follows

$\hat{v}=\cos(\pi/6)\hat{i}+\cos(\pi/3)\hat{j}+\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\pi/6)-\cos^2(\pi/3)}\,\hat{k}$

I don't understand where this equation comes from. Firstly, I don't understand where that entire square root component for $\vec{k}$ comes from. I also don't understand why they are doing $\cos(\pi/3)\hat{j}$ and not $\sin(\pi/3)\hat{j}$ since the $\hat{j}$ vector is associated with the 'y axis'

Answer (score 1):

Generally, let's get the unit vector $\hat{v}$ that makes an angle of $\theta_1$ with $\hat{i}$ and $\theta_2$ with $\hat{j}$.

The size of $\hat{v}$ must be $1$ by definition. Place $\hat{v}$'s tail at the origin, and let's draw the height of $\hat{v}$'s head from the $x$-axis.

The angle is given to be $\theta_1$, so if we project $\hat{v}$ to the $x$-axis, the length should be $\cos\theta_1$. This means the $\hat{i}$-component of $\hat{v}$ is $\cos\theta_1$.

Apply the same logic to the $y$-axis. Project $\hat{v}$ to the $y$-axis, and you'll see why there is no $\sin$ involved.

The size is $1$, so the sum of the squares of the components should be $1$; this is why the $\hat{k}$-component looks like that.

$$\hat{v}=\cos\theta_1\hat{i}+\cos\theta_2\hat{j}+\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta_1-\cos^2\theta_2}\hat{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose our desired vector is $v=(a,b,c)$. We can assume $v$ is a unit vector, so that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. Then

angle between $v$ and x-axis = $\pi/6 \Longrightarrow v \cdot i = \cos(\pi/6)
\Longrightarrow a = \cos(\pi/6)$

angle between $v$ and y-axis = $\pi/3 \Longrightarrow v \cdot j = \cos(\pi/3)
\Longrightarrow b = \cos(\pi/3)$

Then $c = 1 - \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ since $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If a lines makes angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ with $x, y, z$ axes respectively, then its direction cosines are,

$l = \cos\alpha, m =\cos\beta, n=\cos\gamma$,

and [$l^2+m^2 +n^2=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190255/show-that-the-direction-cosines-of-a-vector-satisfies_).

Unit vector parallel to the line is,

$\begin{align}\hat v &= l\hat i + m\hat j + n\hat k \\&= l\hat i + m\hat j + \sqrt{1-l^2-m^2}\hat k\\& = \cos\left(\frac\pi6\right)\hat i +\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)\hat j + \sqrt{1-\cos^2\left(\frac\pi6\right) - \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}\hat k\end{align} $